# Configure android device programmatically

Tags: android, configuration, device

I just wondering if there is a way to configure an android device programmatically. I mean configure wifi, security information,... in fact all the configuration which we can do with the interface.

I know we can already, thanks to adb, install applications from a computer for example but I wanted to find a way to configure all my device from a computer. Do you think there is a way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wondering if there is a way to configure an android device programmatically. I mean configure wifi, security information,... in fact all the configuration which we can do with the interface.

Generally speaking, no. Some things an ordinary SDK application can do, via `WifiManager`, `Settings.System`, etc. Some things require the application to be signed with the firmware signing key or installed on the system partition, such as manipulating `Settings.Secure`. Some things are not exposed at all through APIs, though presumably can be hacked into place on rooted devices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hoped there were an easy way to do this without using SDK or rooted device but apparently no.